# Не знаю как подключить DLL библиотеку

Tags: c, dll

Помогите, не понимаю как подключить dll библиотеку к файлу на С. Допустим хочу подключить user32.dll, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Что такое в вашем понимании "подключить"? Если вы работаете с Visual Studio, то `#pragma comment(lib,"user32")` "подключает" библиотеку при линковке; в других компиляторах можно указать библиотеку в командной строке... но точно ли вы хотите именно этого?

Comment: Для начала стоило бы разобраться с терминологией. Библиотеки .dll не подключаются в файлам на С. Они подключаются к бинарями. А занимается этим линкер, опции которого вам следует освоить.

Comment: От компилятора зависит. MSVC или MinGW?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat MinGW

Comment: Дописать `-luser32` в флаги линковщика, после любых `.c` и `.o` файлов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat большое спасибо